# Limit of $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}-\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We want to find out the limit of

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}-\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}\right)$$

An online calculator says this
[image]

but I don't understand what that means.

I understand that the limit is $0$, but what is the approach when seeing squares like this? We could substitute $u = n^2$, but then what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use the identity that for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$, $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 - b^2$.
So the simplification goes like this:
$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2-1} = \frac{\biggl(\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2-1}\biggr)\biggl(\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}\biggr)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}} $$
Which using the aforementioned identity we can write as:
$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2-1} = \frac{n^2+1-n^2+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}}$$
So that now it is easy to see that:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}} = 0$$

Answer (score 5):

It means that you have to multiply
$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2-1}$$
by
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}}=1.$$
When you simplify you get
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

The conjugate of $\ \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\ $ is $\ \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}.$

Try multiplying $\ \frac{\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}-\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}}{1}\ $ by $\ \frac{\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}+\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}}{\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}+\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}}\ (=1)$ and then see if their answer makes sense.

Although technically, when they say, "multiply by the conjugate of $\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}-\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}\ $ ",
this translates literally into maths as: "multiply by $\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}+\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}.$" What they really meant to say is, "multiply by the conjugate of $\sqrt{n^{2\:}+1\:}-\sqrt{n^{2\:}-1}\ $ over (divided by) itself".